# Filter HTML before and after a class

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I have to remove the following elements from a generated HTML page:

```
<a id="10:51:16.642481" name="10:51:16.642481" href="#10:51:16.642481" class="ts"> 
 [10:51:16]</a> <font class="mj">xxx_xxxn joins the room</font><br/>
```

The only unique key is the class="mj" in the middle of the html elements so I need to filter the first link element  for this block that contains the mj class.

Not more or less.  I have been going round and round trying to make it work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'filter'? You're trying to select, remove it, alter it in some way? Also, you mentioned there's a unique class name of 'mj', does that classname change if someone else joins the room, or is that the class name on all joins? If so, it would seem each timestamp has a class of 'ts', would that not be a proper selector? -- Need more information on what you're doing. :)

Comment: filter = remove  mj is constant for joins, there is a different font class used for messages but the stanzas otherwise are identical.  So all the messages I want to keep have the ts class also  -- j08691 - yes the problem is the link tag does not have the MJ class, I want to remove all links that come immediately before the font tag.. as far a deprecated.. I don't have control over the authorship of the file

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $mjEl = $(".mj");
$mjEl.prev().remove();
$mjEl.next().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to remove everything related to the join message: timestamp, join text, and br. So just to do fun oneliners, we can do:

```
$('.mj').prev().remove().end().next().andSelf().remove();
```

This selects and removes the previous tag, returns to the original handle (`.mj`), then removes itself and the `<br />` tag after.

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/vF4f3/

Comment: AWesome!  Works and to make 15 characters.. Thank You so much

Comment: Very welcome! I see you're new to StackOverflow, so if you're fully satisfied with this response, make sure to mark this as the answer (the checkbox to the left of this post). :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mj').add().prev().remove()
```

Misread. and edited to remove as shown